# Implementing a system for managing a parking

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement a system for managing a parking. This parking has 5 stages and in each stage we have 6 parking spots (a 3D matrix with dimensions 5*2*3) and we know that at least one parking spot is vacant at every moment. When a car enters the parking, we save its number and assign a vacant parking spot to it and when the car wants to exit, again its number is given, so we should search and find it, and then move other cars in order to send out the car. But we want to do min numbers of movements to get the car out of the parking. Each car can be moved to its adjacent, upper, lower, back or front parking spot if the spot is vacant.

Does anyone know an algorithm for solving this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify this a bit better "so we should search and find it, and then move other cars in order to send out the car". In which order? Some spots may block another?

Comment: When the car's number is given we search for the car, and when we find the exact place, according to the vacant place(s), we should move this car or other cars so the car can exit the parking.